# Returning Invalid Models for Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, service-object

I created a Service Object (http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects), which basically creates two models, A and B, sets up the association between them where B belongs to A, and returns A (which in turn you can access B via A given the association).

On error, I return a hash with the error information. As I'm trying to test this method, I'm having an issue now where there are two possible types of returns: either a model (when it passes) or a hash with the error information.

Is this a signal that the design is wrong? I know when you test first (TDD) you avoid such design issues.

If it is an issue, then I know I would need to return an invalid A model. Assuming the model B throws an error on create, how would I still be able to return an invalid A model?

If returning an error hash is okay, how else can I design this method to be testing friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good insight and good question. :-) On the face of it, this seems like a good situation to raise a Ruby exception for the "error" case rather than returning as a hash as a result of the method call.  You can define your own error class (probably should be a subclass of `StandardError`) and include the hash or whatever information you want as part of the error you raise. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html for a discussion of this general topic.

As for checking for the raising of errors in rspec, see the last answer to [How to use RSpec's should_raise with any kind of exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722749/how-to-use-rspecs-should-raise-with-any-kind-of-exception), including links to additional information.

If you want to present your API as a RESTful interface, the consensus seems to be to utilize the HTTP response codes to be to present exceptions, as discussed in [How to handle REST Exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121597/how-to-handle-rest-exceptions) If you do use the exceptional response codes (e.g. 40X) for presenting your exceptions, then the fact that you return a hash in that case and a model in the other case is not a bad smell, imho, as there is no expectation of consistency between the data that accompanies an error and the data that accompanies a successful return. In any event, I don't think returning an "invalid" model in the error case makes any sense, assuming you're not in fact creating/persisting the model in that situation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am building an API and cannot afford to raise a Ruby exception/error as I will need to return the error gracefully to the user in JSON. What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Yes I already do that in my controller. My service returns either a valid model (in which case the controller continues normally) or a hash representing an error (in which case throwing a HTTP response code error etc.). In that case, would it be okay for my service to return either a hash or a valid model, or should I try and see if I can return for example an invalid model? What if model B is the invalid one (see the above question again for B)?

Comment: See updated answer. Even if B is the invalid model, I still wouldn't return it, but instead return whatever information is necessary to appropriately describe the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the type of result.

In rspec...

```
expect(actual).to be_an_instance_of(expected)
expect(actual).to be_a_kind_of(expected)
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. Isn't that a sign that this is poorly designed though?